# Laravel 8 Sanctum: Is it required to extend from Authenticatable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

On the one hand, I have an Eloquent model `User` that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. On the other hand, I have `SanctumUser extends Authenticatable` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens).

What I would like to do is, `User extends Model, SanctumUser`, but multiple inheritance is not possible in PHP 7.x.

I know that some traits are used in `SanctumUser` according to the documentation I've linked above. These traits are: `use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;`. Do you know if they are sufficient if I remove `extends Authenticatable` and replace it with `extends Model` (`User` would extend `SanctumUser`)?

Comment: what is `WordpressMigrateModel` ? you can make it as trait

Comment: @KamleshPaul you can forget it (I've edited the OP :) )

Comment: No I can't make it a trait

Comment: you can create a middle class which `extends Model` then that class `extends SanctumUser` then that final class in model

Comment: `Model` is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` , I can't make it extend `SnctumUser`? Or I didn't understand.

Comment: Which class is the `Authenticatable` here? The documentation only says you need to use the `HasApiTokens` trait in your existing user class. This looks like a documentation miscommunication here because the only `Authenticatable` I'm aware of is an interface so you would implement it

Comment: @apokryfos ah ok well I will try to use all of these things without `Authenticatable`.

Comment: @apokryfos PS : "class User extends Authenticatable" - from the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens) :-)

Comment: The docs may be wrong though. Do you know the fully qualified name of that class?

Comment: nope @apokryfos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Authenticable** as alias for **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User** class has traits which has methods for authentication and authorization

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, MustVerifyEmail;
}
```

Even the default **User** model class which is available with any new standard Laravel installation has it extending the Authenticable class [**use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;**]

Default User Model class in a standard Laravel application has two more traits - Notifiable and HasFactory (since Laravel 8.x)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];
}
```

With Sanctum you may add trait HasApiToken to the User model class.

In order to easily integrate Laravel Sanctum or Jetstream or Laravel UI or Breeze for authentication and authorization to your app, its better to make User class extend Authenticable - plug and play

Comment: As `User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, I don't think it extends `Authenticatable`. So I should add this extension no? in one way or another

Comment: Since `Authenticatable` here is actually an alias of `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` that already extends `Model` and is the Laravel boilerplate User model so no need to extend `Model` yourself since it's already extended. However from your question it's not clear if you're extending the same `Authenticatable` class

Comment: Authenticable which is an alias for **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User** is already extending **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** So when you extend your **App\Models\User** from Authenticable it already has been extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model class via Authenticable

Comment: "Authenticable which is an alias for Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User is already extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model" => Did you mean that `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` extends `Authenticable`?

Comment: **NO**. The class `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User` class and the project's **User** model at `App\Models\User` extends **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User aliased as Authenticable** in the use statement

Comment: Thank you. Well... my `App\Models\User` actually extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, not `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\User`  so it won't work. I need to think about it, but ty.

Comment: @Donkarnash how do you know that Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User is aliased as Authenticable?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo in the earlier comment **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User** aliased as **Authenticable** extends **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** and `App\Models\User` extends **Authenticable**

Comment: See the second block of code in the answer - it's the default **User** class with standard Laravel install. Since the class is named User it can't extend another class named User so in the use statement Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User is aliased as Authenticable

Comment: Ah ok you mean it has a trait = an alias

Comment: ty very much, Sir. :-) I've followed your explanations. As I don't use the default `Model` class but my own (`WordpressMigrateModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`), I have written and will test: `class MyOwnEloquentModelUser extends SanctumUser` ; `SanctumUser extends App\Foundation\Auth\User (the override of Auth\User which is an alias for Authenticable)` and finally `class App\Foundation\Auth\User extends WordpressMigrateModel` (which is the override of `Model`).